# Accessing a div using id without getElementById and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I believe that the standard way in JS to access an element with an id is by using getElementById. If people like to use jQuery, then they probably will use their selectors. But recently I came across a very simple code example which is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="h">Hello</div>
```

JS:

```
h.innerHTML = "Too bad";
```

This is the only code and there are no other variable declarations, just for people to know.
How are we able to access the div element as if it is a Javascript object?

P.S. : The code example works.

Comment: This is a *bad idea* to rely on, as a global variable named `h` will shadow this property and effectively hide it.

Comment: See also [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). AFAIK it has become standadized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How are we able to access the div element as if it is a Javascript
>   object?

`id`s are created by default as **properties of global object** (in global context).

if you do `<div id="h22">Hello</div>` it will create a global variable of `h22`

As per [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-window-nameditem),

> Otherwise return an HTMLCollection rooted at the Document node, whose
>   filter matches only named objects with the name name. (By definition,
>   these will all be elements.)
>
> HTML elements that have an id content attribute whose value is name.

So the `window` can determine in the **order given in the spec** where to pick the value from.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: They are created as `properties` of the global object, which are slightly different then `global variables.`  In particular,  creating a global variable of the same name *shadows* the underlying property.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyamRajesh explained above

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372

Answer (score 2):

Referring from JavaScript The Definitive Guide:

> If you name an element in your HTML document using the id attribute, and if the
>   Window object does not already have a property by that name, the Window object is
>   given a nonenumerable property whose name is the value of the `id` attribute and whose name is the HTMLElement object that represents that document element.
>
> Window object serves as the global object at the top of the scope chain in client-side JavaScript, so this means that the id attributes you use in your HTML documents become global variables accessible to your scripts. If your document includes the element `<button id="okay"/>`, you can refer to that element using the global variable `okay`.

But there are certain exceptions as well. If `window` object has already a property with a name that is also used as an `id` attribute in html document it will not be available as property on window object.

Second if you have an id which is available as window property and we declare a variable with same name as well, then our explicitly created variable will override that window property containing id.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the above answers practically...

**Html:**

```
<div id="foo">
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
alert(window.foo);
console.log(window.foo.innerHTML);
```

**Alert:**

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

**Console:**

```
<p>bar</p>
```